# C# automate constructors refactoring

Tags: c#, constructor, refactoring

I got ask if there is any option to do something like that in C#, lets say we got suche code :

```
class A
{
   public A(int b);
}

class B : A
{
   public B(int b)
   : base(b);
}

class C : B
{
    public C(int b)
    : base(b)
}
```

and now if i want to change in class A "int b" to "Car b" i need to change this in every single class, is it possible to refactor this somehow automate?

Comment: The only thing that's automatic, is parameterless constructors if you specify no explicit instance constructors. In the case the compiler will create a constructor like `public ClassName() : base() { }` (or `protected` in case of an `abstract` class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you can use [C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) :

```
class A<T>
{
    public A(T b)
    {}
}

class B<T> : A<T>
{
   public B(T b)
   : base(b)
    {}
}

class C<T> : B<T>
{
    public C(T b)
    : base(b)
    { }

}
```

You can use the following syntax for int (and use the same principle for a car) :

```
var intVar = new C<int>(10);
```

Otherwise, there is no tool to change all types at once. If you change parameter type to Car, Resharper will propose you to refactor the constructor of derived class.